# Update Query seems to delete memo fields

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, gridview

Okay, I have a Gridview control that I use to edit records in my database. I have parameterized the query also. Here's the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Gray"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="editGridFormat" RowStyle-CssClass="editGridFormat"        
    RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlogTitle" HeaderText="BlogTitle" 
            SortExpression="BlogTitle" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image"
            DataImageUrlFormatString="~/PlaceImages/{0}" ControlStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"
            AlternateText="Something went wrong" 
            NullDisplayText="No picture on file" />
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="PicText">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="PicTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("PicText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("PicText")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="TravelDate" HeaderText="TravelDate" SortExpression="TravelDate" />
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="BeginText">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="BeginTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("BeginText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("BeginText")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Caption" HeaderText="Caption" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
            SortExpression="Country" />
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="EndText">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="EndTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("EndText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("EndText")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table2]" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE [ID] = ?"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Table2 SET [BlogTitle] = ?, 
                                     [Image] = ?, 
                                     [PicText] = ?, 
                                     [TravelDate] = ?, 
                                     [BeginText] = ?, 
                                     [Caption] = ?, 
                                     [City] = ?, 
                                     [Country] = ?, 
                                     [EndText] = ? 
                                     WHERE [ID] = ? " >

    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="BlogTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Image" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PicText" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TravelDate" DbType="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BeginText" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Caption" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EndText" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Not sure if it has to do with the TemplateField control or the Parameter type being a string. The reason I mention the Type property is because in my Access database, they are of the memo type, but the only thing I can see that is halfway comparable is the string type. I'd wager that the string type isn't big enough to hold a memo field, but I don't know what else might be going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, even if I don't edit those particular fields, they still get deleted, all of them.

Comment: It is unlikely that a memo could be larger than a string, you're more likely to run out of memory before reaching the limit of a string.

What happens if you remove the Delete command?

Comment: Oh, I thought strings were limited to 255 characters... Let me check.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Heh. It's as long as an int can be ( 2,147,483,647), although I digress.

Comment: Very good. At least that is not the problem. Removing the gridview's delete button doesn't make a difference. The crazy thing is that it doesn't delete the whole record in the DB, just anything that is a memo field in my DB.

Comment: Is it not an issue with the multiline textbox, try this: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/09/20/ASPNET-Extend-BoundField-Control-Add-MultiLine-support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with memo field. Its the edititemtemplatefields, you are not binding data. Change `Eval` to `Bind`, for example, change this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox id="PicTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("PicText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

to this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox id="PicTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("PicText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Change this :

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox id="BeginTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("BeginText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

to this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox id="BeginTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("BeginText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

And change this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox id="EndTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("EndText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

to this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox id="EndTextBox" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("EndText")%>' textmode="MultiLine" height="300px" width="300px" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I have tested it with access db. Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, that's it. At first I changed the "Eval" in the ItemTemplate control as well, but then I found out that was wrong.